# How to get li id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have

```
<li data-value="id" id="id">
  <img src="src" alt="alt" title="title" />
</li>
```

Also I have script

```
$('.item_slider .thumbs').delegate('li:not(.current)', 'click', function() { //при клике
  var id = $(this).attr('id');
  document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'ID: ' + id;
  alert($(this).attr('data-value'));
});
```

Here two ways to get id. But I always get undefined. What's the problem?

Comment: `.delegate()` is deprecated as in v3.X, use `.on()` instead

Comment: Furthermore, from the look of your code I assume your `li` is inside some sort of loop? If so, keep in mind that `ID` has to be unique in the document

Comment: We don't need your PHP but we do need a [mcve]. Please update your question with one, showing us the exact problem. Other than "undefined", what the the exact error messages you get in the console?

Comment: OK. I edited it. 
The console without errors.  It's a picture slider and with .on() instead .delegate() this script and others doesn't work.

Comment: Show enough html for us to replicate it. There are no classes `item_slider` or `thumbs` shown in the html

Comment: @charlietfl Haha! Thanks a lot! I didn't see the obvious. I really used <li> without class `thumbs`. Thanks!